# How to translate an advanced SQL statement with LEFT OUTER JOIN to LINQ?

Tags: linq-to-sql, outer-join

I have a similar SQL statement as shown [in this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d74dc). For the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [docs] (
  [id] int NOT NULL,
  [rev] int NOT NULL,
  [content] varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ([id],[rev])
) ;
```

and the following data

```
INSERT INTO [docs] ([id], [rev], [content]) VALUES
  (1, 1, 'The earth is flat'),
  (2, 1, 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  (1, 2, 'The earth is flat and rests on a bull``s horn'),
  (1, 3, 'The earth is like a ball.');
```

the SQL statement

```
SELECT d1.*
    FROM docs AS d1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN docs AS d2
    ON (d1.id = d2.id AND d1.rev < d2.rev)
    WHERE d2.id is null
    ORDER BY id;
```

shows only rows with maximum `rev` value for each `id`:

```
id  rev content
1   3   The earth is like a ball.
2   1   One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin
```

**My question:**
How can I translate this statement to LINQ-to-SQL? The problem in my point of view are the `AND` and the `<` in the ON clause.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is best to translate a SQL `LEFT JOIN...WHERE ... = null` into an `EXISTS` which in LINQ is `Any`:

```
var ans = from d1 in docs
          join d2 in docs on d1.id equals d2.id into d2j
          where !d2j.Any(d2 => d1.rev < d2.rev)
          orderby d1.id
          select d1;
```

But, of course, you can translate it into an explicit LINQ null test:

```
using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext()) {
    var query =
        from d1 in context.docs
        join d2 in context.docs on d1.id equals d2.id into d2j
        from d2 in d2j.Where(d2_2 => d1.rev < d2_2.rev).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where d2 == null
        select d1;
    return query.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This solution solves my problem. (I used the second one because it seems closer to the original SQL statement.) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to apply @NetMage's recipe but I got stuck at the `<` condition:

```
   using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
    {
        var query =
            from d1 in context.docs
            join d2 in context.docs on d1.id equals d2.id into jrv
            from x in jrv.Where(x => /* ??? */).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where x equals null
            select x;
        return query.ToArray();
    }
```

The lambda expression in **Where** should be a comparison between `d1.rev` and `d2.rev`. How can I do that?